# Google maps api status

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Google maps api status is showing Inactive as below on https://code.google.com/apis/console/

Key for browser apps (with referers)

API key:
AIzaSyCJVxxxxN3OAHXzE0mxXYV-xxxxx

Referers:

Any referer allowed

Activated on:
May 2, 2013 10:00 AM

Activated by:
 xxx.ssss@gmail.com – you

Obsolete key:
xxxxxxx-Bg5tDJtambckISYxGThjVDAgxxxxx

Status:Inactive

Any ideas why the status is inactive and how can I activate it

Answer (score 1):

I was also searching for a solution right know and it seems like "Status: Inactive" doesn't mean your current API key, but your obsolete key. I tried to regenerate a key and now my status changed to "Active until Aug 28...", which is in exactly 24 hours, because your old key is only available for this time after you regenerated a new one.